# Scaling vmalert with many rules

Tags: monitoring, victoriametrics

I use vmalert and victoria metrics in my monitoring architecture and I have a very big amount of rules (about 20000).
That caused the iteration duraion to be higher than the iteration interval and alerting to be slower.

My solution was to create multiple vmalert deployments and split the rules between them. It worked (each deployment had a low iteration duration), but now I have to create a vmalert deployment once a while, and create a spliting machenism of the rules between the deployments. Do you have a better solution?
Would love to get some help from pepole who have many rules too

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The same question was asked by OP at https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/4756
Please follow the discussion there.